# show that : $\mathcal{S}\cap\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ making the function $x \mapsto x^2$ measurable.

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the set of symmetrical subset of $\mathbb{R}$ $\big($ i.e. $\mathcal{S}:= \{A\subset\mathbb{R}:\forall x \in\mathbb{R}~~,~~ x \in A \Leftrightarrow -x \in A\}$$\big)$.

**Problem:**

> I want to show that : $\mathcal{S}\cap\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ making the function $f:x \mapsto x^2$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, $(\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B} (\mathbb{R}))$ - measurable.

**My effort**

We have $$\sigma \big(f^{-1}(\mathcal{B} (\mathbb{R})\big)=\sigma\bigg(f^{-1}\bigg(\sigma\bigg(\big\{]-\infty,q]:q\in\mathbb{Q}\big\}\bigg)\bigg)\bigg)=\sigma\bigg(\bigg\{f^{-1}\big(]-\infty,q]\big):q\in\mathbb{Q}\big\}\bigg)\bigg)\bigg)=\sigma(\{[-q,q]:q\in\mathbb{Q}\})$$

Then $\mathcal{A}=\sigma(\{[-q,q]:q\in\mathbb{Q}\})$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ making the function $f:x \mapsto x^2$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, $(\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B} (\mathbb{R}))$ - measurable.

Is what I wrote true? If so, you can help me show that $\sigma(\{[-q,q]:q\in\mathbb{Q}\})=\mathcal{S}\cap\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$?

An idea please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a much simpler approach:

We want to show that if $\mathcal{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra which makes $x^2$ measurable, then $\mathcal{S} \cap \mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{M}$.

So let $E \in \mathcal{S} \cap \mathcal{B}$. We want to show $E \in \mathcal{M}$ too.

Well, there's only one fact we know about $\mathcal{M}$ (it renders $x^2$ measurable) and one fact we know about $E$ ($x \in E \iff -x \in E)$, so we have to use those facts somehow.

Now $x^2$ being $\mathcal{M}$-measurable means that $(x^2)^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{M}$ for any borel set $B$. This is useful, since we want to show $E \in \mathcal{M}$. If we can we show that $E = (x^2)^{-1}(B)$ for some borel set $B$ then we're done!

The dream now is to write

$$
E = 
(x^2)^{-1}(B) = 
\{ x ~|~ x^2 \in B \} = 
\{ \pm \sqrt{x} ~|~ x \in B \}.
$$
But here is where we use our assumption on $E$! There is an obvious reason that as set wouldn't be of this form: this set is symmetric. But thankfully we know that $E$ is symmetric too, so this is not an issue!

Reversing the definition above shows $B = \{ x ~|~ \sqrt{|x|} \in E \}$ works. Do you see why $E = (x^2)^{-1}(B)$? More importantly, do you see why this set $B$ is borel? (Here it is important that $E$ is borel too, so we use our last remaining assumption.)

So at the end of the day, if $E \in \mathcal{S} \cap \mathcal{B}$, we've seen that $E = (x^2)^{-1}(B)$ for some borel $B$ as defined above. But then $E \in \mathcal{M}$ too since $x^2$ is $\mathcal{M}$-measurable.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: fixed ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x) = x^2$ we see that $\{x | f(x) < \alpha \} = (-\sqrt{\alpha},\sqrt{\alpha})$ if $\alpha >0$ and $\emptyset$ otherwise. Hence the smallest $\sigma$ algebra
that makes $f$ (Borel) measurable is $\Sigma = \sigma(\{(-x,x)\})$.

We want to show that $\Sigma = \mathcal{S} \cap \mathcal{B}$. (I have dropped the $\mathbb{R}$ notation.)

Note that $\mathcal{S}$ is a $\sigma$ algebra and so $\mathcal{S} \cap \mathcal{B}$ is a $\sigma$ algebra.
Since $(-x,x) \in \mathcal{S} \cap \mathcal{B}$ we see that
$\Sigma \subset \mathcal{S} \cap \mathcal{B}$.

To show that $\mathcal{S} \cap \mathcal{B} \subset \Sigma$, let $\mathcal{C} = \{ B \in \mathcal{B} | \{B\} \cap \mathcal{S} \subset \Sigma 
 \}$. It is straightforward to
see that $\mathcal{C}$ is a $\sigma$ algebra and that $(a,b) \in \mathcal{C}$ and
hence $\mathcal{C} = \mathcal{B}$.